# Hadoop shutdown, how to stop hadoop in pseudo distributed mode?

Tags: hadoop

I try to use stop-dfs.sh to kill hadoop process, but failed. Shall I have to use brutal force kill -9?

```
[root@trdstorm sbin]# sudo ./stop-dfs.sh
16/07/26 10:19:56 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Stopping namenodes on [localhost]
root@localhost's password:
localhost: Permission denied, please try again.
root@localhost's password:
localhost: no namenode to stop
root@localhost's password:
localhost: no datanode to stop
Stopping secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
root@0.0.0.0's password:
0.0.0.0: no secondarynamenode to stop  --> no secondaryname to stop, from grep, it has.
16/07/26 10:20:33 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
[root@trdstorm sbin]# ps -aef | grep secondary
hadoop    7406     1  0 Jul15 ?        00:09:38 /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/bin/java -Dproc_secondarynamenode -Xmx1000m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.log.dir=/usr/local/hadoop/logs -Dhadoop.log.file=hadoop.log -Dhadoop.home.dir=/usr/local/hadoop -Dhadoop.id.str=hadoop -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,console -Dhadoop.policy.file=hadoop-policy.xml -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.log.dir=/usr/local/hadoop/logs -Dhadoop.log.file=hadoop-hadoop-secondarynamenode-trdstorm.log -Dhadoop.home.dir=/usr/local/hadoop -Dhadoop.id.str=hadoop -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,RFA -Dhadoop.policy.file=hadoop-policy.xml -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,RFAS -Dhdfs.audit.logger=INFO,NullAppender -Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,RFAS -Dhdfs.audit.logger=INFO,NullAppender -Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,RFAS -Dhdfs.audit.logger=INFO,NullAppender -Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,RFAS org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode
```

root     26651 26238  0 10:20 pts/2    00:00:00 grep secondary

+++++++++++++++++++after making passwordless ssh+++++++++++++++++
+++++++++++++++++++command to stop hadoop process++++++++++++++++

```
[hadoop@trdstorm ~]$ ssh localhost
Last login: Tue Jul 26 17:29:00 2016 from localhost
[hadoop@trdstorm ~]$ cd /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/
[hadoop@trdstorm sbin]$ sudo ./stop-all.sh
[sudo] password for hadoop:
This script is Deprecated. Instead use stop-dfs.sh and stop-yarn.sh
16/07/26 17:32:58 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Stopping namenodes on [localhost]
root@localhost's password:
localhost: no namenode to stop
root@localhost's password:
localhost: no datanode to stop
Stopping secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
root@0.0.0.0's password:
0.0.0.0: no secondarynamenode to stop
16/07/26 17:33:21 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
stopping yarn daemons
no resourcemanager to stop
root@localhost's password:
localhost: no nodemanager to stop
no proxyserver to stop
[hadoop@trdstorm sbin]$ ps -aef | grep second
hadoop    7406     1  0 Jul15 ?        00:09:53 /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/bin/java -Dproc_secondarynamenode -Xmx1000m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.log.dir=/usr/local/hadoop/logs -Dhadoop.log.file=hadoop.log -Dhadoop.home.dir=/usr/local/hadoop -Dhadoop.id.str=hadoop -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,console -Dhadoop.policy.file=hadoop-policy.xml -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.log.dir=/usr/local/hadoop/logs -Dhadoop.log.file=hadoop-hadoop-secondarynamenode-trdstorm.log -Dhadoop.home.dir=/usr/local/hadoop -Dhadoop.id.str=hadoop -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,RFA -Dhadoop.policy.file=hadoop-policy.xml -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,RFAS -Dhdfs.audit.logger=INFO,NullAppender -Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,RFAS -Dhdfs.audit.logger=INFO,NullAppender -Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,RFAS -Dhdfs.audit.logger=INFO,NullAppender -Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,RFAS org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode
hadoop   29825 29295  0 17:33 pts/3    00:00:00 grep second
```

Comment: I believe a step of setting up Hadoop is passwordless SSH access

Comment: I have set password, also I have SSH access. Are there passwordless one step of setting up Hadoop by SSH access?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. Did you try to `ssh localhost` to see if you could connect to own machine?

Comment: @cricket_007 yes, I could ssh localhost,but I need to input password.

Comment: Then that means you haven't established a key-pair for passwordless SSH, which not sure about pseudo distributed mode, but you have to do for root user and regular user

Comment: Are there document to do passwordless SSH?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118289/discussion-between-user84592-and-cricket-007).

Comment: Any documentation detailing setting up private-public key pairs should suffice. I've had success following the Hortonworks documentation, but at that point if you just want to learn Hadoop, download the HDP Sandbox or Cloudera Quickstart VM.  https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.4.2/index.html

Comment: Below question text +++++++++, is command output when I make ssh localhost passwordless. I still could stop hadoop process.

Comment: You don't actually need to ssh into the machine, just it is recommended to set it up to be possible by the Hadoop binaries. In any case, the I don't think you are required to use sudo to shutdown services as long as you've established access rights correctly (which is a complex process to get correct)

Comment: Anyways... Sorry to misguide you. To address the problem at hand, you may have to `kill -9` that secondary namenode process. Though you may want to grep for java instead and see what other processes exist

Comment: Hi, So can I make a initial conclusion: to shutdown Hadoop process as pseudo distributed mode is not trivial. One need deep study.

Comment: Not necessarily, you simply seem to have child processes that weren't killed due to some error in configuration (which can happen in a full hadoop setup)

Comment: @cricket_007 very much thanks your time, but I have used brutal force, kill -9. So I could not give your score since I could not verify. Thank you very much!

Comment: "Give your score"? I didn't give an answer, just comments. I still recommend using one of those virtual machines with Hadoop pre-built

Answer (score 0):

to stop all the services

```
sudo ./stop-all.sh
```

Comment: after ssh localhost, [block@trdstorm sbin]$ jps
22902 Jps,        after exit, [block@trdstorm local]$ jps
23133 Jps

Comment: I am not using services. I just start hadoop by ./start-dfs.sh and ./start-yarn.sh.